# How does the toggling of the status column in V$session work?

Tags: oracle, session, plsql

I was wanting to know how does the status column in `V$session` work. I understand that the column shows if a particular session is active or inactive. I also understand that a session is active when it is executing an sql statement. However, I wanted to know what is the status of a session when a plsql block or a program is being executed.

For eg: I have a plsql procedure like below

```
 PROCEDURE XYZ is
.
. 
begin
<SQL statement>
.
.
<some other plsql code>
.
. 
<dbms output statements>
.
.
<SQL statement>
.
.
<some other plsql code>
.
.
<dbms output statements>

End XYZ;
```

I wanted to know that when once the sql statement finishes and the other stuff like other plsql code or dbms output statements are executing, **what is the status of the session during that time?** is it active or inactive as no sqls are running at that moment.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

It should switch between *`ACTIVE`* and *`INACTIVE`* status; from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223)

> Status of the session:
>
> - ACTIVE - Session currently executing SQL
> - INACTIVE
> - KILLED - Session marked to be killed
> - CACHED - Session temporarily cached for use by Oracle*XA
> - SNIPED - Session inactive, waiting on the client

Nothing about running PLSQL. But you could however be locking table and objects with PLSQL treatment alone, so you would have your session only waiting for commit instead of being *`ACTIVE`*.

## edit

However, since you can't call PLSQL out of nothing; PLSQL is called e.g. from `sqlplus` client... This might count as `SQL` to Oracle. So the whole procedure would in this case enable the session as *`ACTIVE`*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special rule for executing procedures. If the session is currently waiting on a lock or spinning on some cpu-intensive non-SQL operation that will be reflected in the status regardless of whether the task is executed as part of a procedure or not.

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-28E2DC75-E157-4C0A-94AB-117C205789B9.htm#REFRN30223) defines 'ACTIVE' as 'Currently executing SQL', but from a quick test my session remained 'ACTIVE' when waiting on a locked object, waiting on `dbms_lock.sleep` and incrementing a counter in a loop. I don't know if there is any official list of actions do or don't count as 'ACTIVE', though.